# Trying to access Cloud composer APIs

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-composer

I am using below code to modify Airflow dag status.

```
statusObject = {"state": "failed"}
AUTH_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
CREDENTIALS, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=[AUTH_SCOPE])
authed_session = AuthorizedSession(CREDENTIALS)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json'}

url = "https://{composer-name}.composer.googleusercontent.com/api/v1/dags/" + dag_run.conf["dag_id"] + "/dagRuns/" + dag_run.conf["cancel_dag_id"]

response= authed_session.request("PATCH", url, json=statusObject,headers=headers)
```

I am getting `401 unauthorised` because the service account I am using has `access_type = 'online'`.

How can I make this API request or set `access_type='offline'` programmatically?

Comment: You can set the `access_type` parameter by specifying `access_type` as a keyword argument when calling the `flow.authorization_url` method as: `authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url( access_type='offline', include_granted_scopes='true')`. For more information you can refer to this [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_7). Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: Hi @Abhishek Singh, did the above comment help?

Comment: I figured out the issue was because service account was more than 64 character not  access_type = offline.

Answer (score 1):

@Abhishek Singh, As you have mentioned in the comment, issue can be resolved by limiting the character size of service account ID.

The ID must be between 6 and 30 characters, and can contain lowercase alphanumeric characters and dashes. After you create a service account, you cannot change its name. The service account's name appears in the email address that is provisioned during creation, in the format `SA_NAME @ PROJECT_ID`.

For more information this [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) can be referred.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.